# Simple TIdHttpServer Example supporting SSL

Tags: delphi, indy, indy10

Hoping someone can provide me a simple **TIdHttpServer** example which supports SSL.  Using Delphi2007 and Indy10.  I have the following to create/setup the server and ioHandler:

```
ServerIOHandler := TIdServerIOHandlerSSLOpenSSL.Create(self);
ServerIOHandler.SSLOptions.CertFile := 'mycert.pem';
ServerIOHandler.SSLOptions.KeyFile := 'mycert.pem';
ServerIOHandler.SSLOptions.RootCertFile := 'mycert.pem';
ServerIOHandler.SSLOptions.Method := sslvSSLv23;
ServerIOHandler.SSLOptions.Mode := sslmServer;

ServerIOHandler.SSLOptions.VerifyDepth := 1;
ServerIOHandler.SSLOptions.VerifyMode := [sslvrfPeer,sslvrfFailIfNoPeerCert,sslvrfClientOnce];

IdHTTPServer1 := TIdHTTPServer.Create;
IdHTTPServer1.AutoStartSession := True;
IdHTTPServer1.SessionState := True;
IdHTTPServer1.OnCommandGet := IdHTTPServer1CommandGet;
idHttpServer1.ParseParams := True;
idHttpServer1.DefaultPort := 80;
idHttpServer1.IOHandler := ServerIOHandler;
IdHTTPServer1.Active := True;
```

**mycert.pem** was created using openssl with this command:

```
openssl req -x509 -nodes -days 365 -newkey rsa:1024 -keyout mycert.pem -out mycert.pem
```

Right away I think there is something wrong because I am using the same file for **CertFile, KeyFile, RootCertFile**.

I entered blanks for prompts with the exception being the common name.  That I was sure to set to the domain name I am using (let's say hypothetically it is **myexample.com**).

In a browser if I hit **http://myexample.com** results in exception: **Error accepting connection with SSL**.  Hitting **https://myexample.com** never makes it to my code.

**January 30 NOTE**  - I used sslbuddy to generate the keys.  And this still did not work.  I then commented out the following lines and it worked:

```
ServerIOHandler.SSLOptions.VerifyDepth := 1;
ServerIOHandler.SSLOptions.VerifyMode := [sslvrfPeer,sslvrfFailIfNoPeerCert,sslvrfClientOnce];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to listen on 443, you need to bind to it... (If you want normal HTTP traffic as well bind also to 80)

```
 IdHTTPServer1.Bindings.Add.Port := 80;
 IdHTTPServer1.Bindings.Add.Port := 443;
```

If listening to more than one port for HTTP and HTTPS, when processing connections you need to allow for either normal or encrypted traffic depending on the port number.  There's an **OnQuerySSLPort** event that you need to use to disable SSL on port 80.

About certificates... it depends if you are using your own CA or using a well established public CA.  Just be aware you should also be setting the **OnGetPassword** event (ServerIOHandler) in order to tell the server your key password.

Comment: Thank you very much Darian.  Was not aware of the Bindings.Add.Port.  At this stage I just want to use my own CA; but I am familiar with getting certificates from a authority such as GoDaddy.  I was tinkering with the OnGetPassword event.  At one point when I created the certificate with openssl it asked for a password.  But use the statement I include in the original post it does not.  Does Indy only work with password protected certificates?

Comment: It's OpenSSL that is using the certificates - Indy is just calling OpenSSL methods.  I haven't used this without setting a password...I'd assume the default password to be blank so the OnGetPassword event would be optional in that case.

Comment: Ok - making some progress here. I was able to generate a password protected file with openssl.  I have verified it is actually using the password (if I morph the password in the ongetpassword handler it throws exception).  Now when I try to hit a https url I get "Error Accepting connection with ssl.  EOF was observed that violates the protocol" messages.  Any idea?  And this is then followed by "SSL3_GET_CLIENT_CERTIFICATE: peer did not return a certificate" exceptions.  Is there some event I need to handle which returns the certificate?

Comment: Looking at this document: http://www.madboa.com/geek/openssl/#cert-self  Looks like there is more for me to do (i.e. generating keys).

Comment: Thank you.  See my January 30 note.  I think in the end the problem was the VerifyDepth and VerifyMode parameters.